# Why do they want an 'unsigned char*' and not just a normal string or 'char*'

Tags: c++, c, hash

**EDIT: After taking adivce I have rearranged the parameters & types. But the application crashes when I call the digest() function now? Any ideas whats going wrong?**

```
const std::string message = "to be encrypted";
unsigned char* hashMessage;

SHA256::getInstance()->digest( message, hashMessage ); // crash occurs here, what am I doing wrong?
printf("AFTER: n"); //, hashMessage); // line never reached
```

I am using an open source implementation of the SHA256 algorithm in C++. My problem is understanding how to pass a unsigned char* version of my string so it can be hashed?

This is the function that takes a unsigned char* version of my string:

```
void SHA256::digest(const std::string &buf, unsigned char *dig) {
    init();
    update(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(buf.c_str()), static_cast<unsigned int>(buf.length()));
    final();
    digest(dig);
}
```

**How can I convert my string(which I want hashed) to an unsigned char*?**

The following code I have made causes a runtime error when I go to print out the string contents:

```
const std::string hashOutput;
char message[] = "to be encrypted";

printf("BEFORE: %s bb\n", hashOutput.c_str());
SHA256::getInstance()->digest( hashOutput, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(message) );
printf("AFTER: %s\n", hashOutput.c_str()); // CRASH occurs here
```

PS: I have been looking at many implementations of SHA256 & they all take an unsigned char* as the message to be hashed. Why do they do that? Why not a char* or a string instead?

Comment: This code does not make very much sense. Why is your `message` mutable any your `hashOutput` `const`? What are you doing to avoid buffer overruns? Please add a link to the documentation for the library that you are using.

Comment: @Mankarse: I am using the sha256 algorithm implemented here: http://tinypasswordmanager.googlecode.com/svn

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that makes already given answers not answering your question anymore. If some advice here answered this question, then accept that advice. If you run into further problems that can't be solved in a few comments, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `unsigned char` is used is that it has guaranteed behaviours under bitwise operations, shifts, and overflow.

`char`, (when it corresponds to `signed char`) does not give any of these guarantees, and so is far less useable for operations intended to act directly on the underlying bits in a string.

---

The answer to the question: "why does it crash?" is "you got lucky!". Your code has undefined behaviour. In short, you are writing through a pointer `hashMessage` that has never been initialised to point to any memory. A short investigation of the source code for the library that you are using reveals that it requires the `digest` pointer to point to a block of valid memory that is at least `SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE` `char`s long.

To fix this problem, all that you need to do is to make sure that the pointer that you pass in as the `digest` argument (`hashMessage`) is properly initialised, and points to a block of memory of sufficient size. In code:

```
const std::string message("to be encrypted");
unsigned char hashMessage[SHA256_DIGEST_SIZE];

SHA256::getInstance()->digest( message, hashMessage );

//hashMessage should now contain the hash of message.
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the parameters around the wrong way. Buf is the input (data to be hashed) and dig is the output digest ( the hash).

Furthermore, a hash is binary data. You will have to convert said binary data into some string representation prior to printing it to screen. Normally, people choose to use a hexadecimal string for this.

Comment: Ah I see, I feel stupid :P I have made the changes(see edit). Now I get a crash when I call digest() though?

Comment: @Ryan: either hexadecimal or base64 adequately work. I myself prefer base64 because it is somewhat shorter.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how a SHA256 hash is produced but maybe it involves some sort of arithmetic that needs to be done on a unsigned data type.

Why does it matter? Get a `char*` from your string object by calling the c_str() method then cast to `unsigned char*`.